# How to map Transient field to query result field?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have a `BSetup` entity with two `@Transient` fields `productName` and `volumeUnit` which come from the `Product` table which is linked by the foreign key `productId` but the values of both fields is always null. First, am I using `@Transient` correctly in this instance or should I be using another method to retrieve and set data from another table linked by a foreign key? I will have several queries in my `BSetupRespository` that link the `BSetup` and `Product` table together so it would be ideal if the mapping was done automatically.

Repository

```
public interface BSetupRespository extends JpaRepository<BSetup, Long> {

    @Query(value = " SELECT bs, p.name as productName, p.volumeUnit as volumeUnit " +
            " FROM BSetup bs " +
            "   INNER JOIN Product p ON p.id = bs.productId " +
            " WHERE bs.wgId = ?1 ")
    List<BinSetup> getSetup(Long wgId);

}
```

Entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name="b_setup")
@Data
public class BSetup implements Serializable {
        
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", updatable = false)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "product_id")
    private Long productId;
    
    @Column(name = "wg_id",updatable = false, insertable = false)
    private Long wgId;

    @JsonSerialize
    @JsonDeserialize
    @Transient
    private String productName;

    public String getProductName() { return productName; }

    @JsonSerialize
    @JsonDeserialize
    @Transient
    private String volumeUnit;

    public String getVolumeUnit() { return volumeUnit; }
}
```

Service

```
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public WGIO.Response getWGInfo(final Long wgId) {

    WGIO.Response response = new WGIO.Response();

    List<BSetup> bSetup = bSetupRespository.getSetup(wgId);
    response.setBSetup(bSetup);
    return response;
}
```

Even if I try setting it manually it doesnt work

```
List<BSetup> bSetup = setupRespository.getSetup(wgId);
if(!CollectionUtils.isEmpty(bSetup)) {
        bSetup.forEach(b->{
            b.setProductName(b.getProductName()); // still null
            b.setVolumeUnit(b.getVolumeUnit()); // still null
        });
    }
```

Comment: I'm confused. ` javax.persistence.Transient` is used to ignore the field when persisting, why are you using it? JPA is not going to set or read the value. Also why are you using `Long productId` and not `Product product`

Answer (score 0):

A field `@Transient` is going to be ignored.

An association with a foreign key should be mapped with something like:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="b_setup")
@Data
public class BSetup implements Serializable {
        
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", updatable = false)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne // or @OneToOne, it depends from your schema
    @JoinColumn(name="product_id)
    private Product product;
    
    ...
}
```

With this mapping, when yuo read `BSetup` you also get the associated `Product`.

Here's a link to the [Hibernate ORM documentation about mapping associations](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#associations)

Then you can use this JPQL query:

```
select bs from BSetup bs inner join bs.p p where p.id = ?
```